# Don't replace asterisk only if preceded by a specific word in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to write a regex that does not replace * if preceded by the word 'pay', else replace * by a space, in a dataframe column.

For example, if I have this dataframe: 
`pd.DataFrame({'a':['pay * jaf',"df*kafds","*fjas","kf8* 8*jkds"]})`, it should leave * only in the first row, and then for the rest, it should replace it with a space.

So if I do `df["col"] = df["col"].str.replace(pat, ' ')`, it should return `pd.DataFrame({'a':['pay * jaf',"df kafds"," fjas","kf8  8 jkds"]})`

I cannot come up with the regex that does it. Currently, I have this pattern `pay.*(?=\*)`, but it does not work. Seems like it should be simple, but I am a beginner in regex. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, in that you've figured out that you want a [lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), but you've got your logic around the opposite way.

You want a pattern that matches all `*` asterisks, but with the condition that the asterisk is not preceeded by the word `pay`.

```
pat = '(?<!pay.*)\*'
```

This pattern means "if the current position is not immediately preceeded (`(?<!`) by the letters `pay` and any number of characters (`.*`), then match an asterisk (`\*`) at the current position".

For comparison, your pattern `pay.*(?=\*)` means "match any `pay` followed by any number of characters (`.*`) with the condition that the matched region is immediately followed  (`(?=`) by an asterisk (`\*`)".

Comment: Thanks Slobor. However, when I run this code `df["col"].str.replace('(?<!paypal.*)\*', " ")`, I get `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern` error.